# Pointers and Functions in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, function, pass-by-value

From the lectures notes of a course at university, on "call-by-value":

> ```
> void fun(int *ip)
>
> {
>
> *ip =100;
>
> }
> ```

called by

> ```
> int n=2;  
>
> int *np;
>
> np = &n; 
>
> fun(np);
> ```
>
> would change the value of n to 100.

When we say "int *ip", what exactly do we mean? A pointer of type integer? If so, when we call fun() with np as its argument, shouldn't there be an error as np has the address of n, which is not an integer?

And then, we change the value of ip to 100, so doesn't that mean that n now has the value that's in the "memory slot" with the address 100? I am sure I am missing something. :)

Comment: You can also just write `int n = 2; fun(&n);` if you just want to change the value of a variable.

Comment: np is of type "int*", if that helps your comprehension any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A pointer of type integer?

No, a pointer *to* an integer.

> when we call fun() with np as its argument, shouldn't there be an error as np has the address of n, which is not an integer?

`n` is an integer so there’s no problem. `&n`, `np` and `ip` all have the same type in your code: `int*`.

> And then, we change the value of ip to 100

No … we change the value of `*ip`, not of `ip`. That is, we change the value that `ip` *points to* (which is also sometimes called the *pointee*).

Comment: One thing that might help clarifying here is to stress that the type is `int*`, even though it's written `int *ip` - C++ allows us to write it either way (`int* ip` or `int *ip`) but both mean the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, but there's a gotcha: If you say `int* ip, ip2;`, `ip` is a pointer to `int`, but `ip2` is just an `int`.  The `*` associates with the name, not the type.  Thus people write `int *ip;` to remind themselves of this.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I'm aware of this - the comment I made was not meaning to imply that it was specific to C++; I merely used C++ because that is what the OP asked about. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you use `int *` as a parameter type of `fun` you are saying it accepts a pointer to an int.  Since `np` is a pointer to an int passing it into `fun` is ok.

`np` and `ip` are pointing to the address of `n`, so when you assign a value like `*ip = 42`, it will assign the value of 42 to the memory location that `ip` is pointing to - which is `n`.

Comment: So "int *pointer" means "a pointer to an integer". But of what type is that variable/element? Because to me *pointer (which is a value) and np (which is an address) are not the same thing.

Comment: In a declaration of a pointer you use `int*` to indicate that you want a pointer to an int. When later using the pointer as a variable, you add a `*`, like in `*ip`, to access the value the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the sample code is called **pass by pointer**. Your function has a parameter of type *pointer to integer*. So the value passed to the function is *the address* of the variable `n`. The function assigns `100` to the variable (i.e. a memory location) *pointed to* by the pointer parameter `ip`. The star `*` is the *dereference operator* in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

in fun(), you aren't changing the value of ip to 100, you're changing the at the memory location pointed to by ip.

Answer (score 0):

`type*` used as a type means "a pointer to that type"

common use is `int *var`, but I like to write it as `int* var` as that makes it a better distinction from dereferenceing a pointer, i.e. `*ptr`.

so `int* a` means, a is a pointer to an object of type int, `*a` means the object pointed to by a and `&a` means the address of object a.

Answer (score 0):

think of `np` as of type `int*`. Bear in mind that for this purpose the asterisk and the `int` together make a "pointer to int" type, and are not separatable.

Answer (score 0):

`ip` is a pointer, with `ip*` you access the "memory slot" it's pointing to. `np` is also a pointer. Using `&n` you assign the address of the memory slot of `n` to `np`. So when calling `fun()`, inside `fun()` the only memory slot that's accessed is the one of `n` and thus to `n` 100 is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Some confusion is possible here because both n and np store numbers - however, when compiling, the compiler will use the numbers differently; that is, while

```
n++;
```

and

```
np++;
```

are both actually arithmetic operations, the generated assembly is different. It is important to remember that, ultimately, all of the data in the computer are numbers. They become different *types* of data merely because we treat them differently.

Specifically with regards to your example,

```
*np = 100;
```

you need to remember that the `*` means *dereference*, and that operation happens before the assignment. It may be clearer with superfluous parenthesis:

```
(* (np) ) = 100;
```

or in a different context:

```
int n = *np;
```

Now, I must say, it warms my heart when you say,

> we change the value of ip to 100, so doesn't that mean that n now has the value that's in the "memory slot" with the address 100?
>   as it belies what I regard as an important understanding. However, I believe I am right when I say, you must go out of your way to do that kind of thing to pointers:

```
static_cast<int>(np) = 100;
```

This would do what you described, because it tells the computer to treat the number that is np as a different kind of number; in the same way that `static_cast<char*>(np)` would treat the number np points to as a character, rather than as an integer.